# How to get a footer to stay at the bottom of a html page after resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found multiple other questions on this in which all of the answers did not work and this has ranged from using jquery and keeping track of screen sizes to dynamically change css of the footer to just using `@media`. None of this has worked and I cannot figure out why.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Netters - Nets for All</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex:1;
        background-color: #2b2b2b;
      }
      
      header {
        background-color: #7f60d7;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        
      }
      
      nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
      
      nav a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      nav a:hover {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
      }
      
      section {
        padding: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #2b2b2b;
        color:white;
      }
      
      section h2 {
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      
      section ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      section li {
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      
      footer {
        background-color: #7f60d7;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .active{
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
      .dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #7f60d7;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #a289e9;
  }
 h2>a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  h2>a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
color:#d8c9ff;
  }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="netters.png" alt="" width="269" height="100">
      <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <li><a class="active" href="products.html">Products</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="sportNet.html">Sports Nets</a>
                <a href="fishingNet.html">Fishing Nets</a>
                <a href="agricultureNet.html">Agriculture Nets</a>
                <a href="industrialNet.html">Industrial Nets</a>
              </div></div>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section id="products">
        <h1 style="border: solid thin black;display: inline;font-size: 4em;">Our Products</h1>
        <ul>
          <div>
            <h2 ><a href="sportNet.html"  >Sports Nets</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 ><a href="fishingNet.html">Fishing Nets</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2><a href="agricultureNet.html">Agriculture Nets</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2><a href="industrialNet.html">Industrial Nets</a></h2>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
  <footer style="position:relative;left:0;bottom:0;width: 100%;">
    <p>Netters &copy; 2023. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </footer>

</html>
```

When it resizes it pulls the footer from the bottom of the page to the middle of the page.

I tried switching the position from relative to absolute which works for one but not the other which is the case for the other monitor which works on relative instead of absolute. There are multiple questions here about it and I can verify almost every one hasn't worked in my case. I have tried `@media` with `min-width`/`max-width` or `min-height`/`max-height`

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in your css footer

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Then when I put the browser in a smaller monitor and it becomes scrollable the footer overlays the text on the screen making it impossible to read the text in the body